# Merge UILocalNotifications with same firedate

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

Is there any way that two (or more) UILocalNotifications which fires at the exact same time can be merged together. Let's say that I have two reminders that fires at 12.00PM today:

1) Wash the dishes
2) Buy milk

What I have right now is (since I have scheduled two separate timers) two single alerts coming up; one telling me to wash the dishes and the other to buy milk.

What I try to achieve is one alert, telling me both to wash the dishes and to buy milk.

I have read that for tasks like this one, APNS might be a better choice, but due to lack of a proper and stable server, and to keep the complexity as low as possible, I am researching to find out whether this could be done just using UILocalNotifications.

The only solution I have come up with is to create some logic that checks if there's any notifications with the same fire dates and if there is, removing them both and creating a new, merged notification with information from both.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only solution I have come up with is to create some logic that checks if there's any notifications with the same fire dates and if there is, removing them both and creating a new, merged notification with information from both.

That's exactly the way to go. It should not be very difficult to implement, either.

Comment: I thought so. But I have a dilemma: I need to be able to show all notifications in order to edit firedate, details etc. When first merged together, I'm afraid it's not trivial to disassemble them again. Have you got any suggestions on how to do this in a clever way?

Comment: What's wrong in _not_ consolidating them in the first place. Perhaps the user wants to see separate notifications if they created separate tasks for it. Otherwise, you should keep two lists: one with the separate notifications the user created, one with the consolidated notifications for the system.

Comment: I have considered keeping all records in the database and then search for multiple firedates every time I update / add / delete, to keep a consolidated list for the system as you mention. But I think it is very clear that one such task needs some logic after all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use singletons to achieve this
http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-scheduling-local-notifications-using-a-singleton-class/

Comment: Ankit would you mind explain how mugunthkumar's blog post will help me solve my problem? I see that is a quite elegante way to put all notification responsibility into one place, but I can't see how that'd help me out here.

Comment: probably you can collect all the notification data with nearby timestamp at one place and publish it together